# Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, dynamic, runtime, meta-tags

I have a problem with my MVC3 web application. I am getting an RuntimeBinderException.

There is a problem with my dynamic page metatags. Meta tags are set from .resx files. I think it can't access the resources at runtime. And also people in other countries can't access the website. There is a connection time-out error. But we are in USA and we can access the website. Do you have any idea?

My metatags is below;

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Description = Glob.HomeDescription;
        ViewBag.Keywords = Glob.HomeKeywords; ;
        ViewBag.Title = Glob.HomeTitle;

        var data = new HomeData();
        data.AnnouncementLists = _announcementService.GetAnnouncementList(LanguageId).Data;
        data.FeedBackLists = _feedbackService.GetFeedbackListHome(LanguageId).Data;
        data.Newfeedback = new FeedBackDTO { Context = "", Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now, FeedBackId = Guid.NewGuid(), LanguageId = LanguageId, Status = false, LanguageName = "", Who = "" };
        return View(data);
    }
```

The error is below;

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Message: 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'Description'

Stack Trace: at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.SubmitError(CError pError) at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler.SubmitError(CParameterizedError error) at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.MemberLookup.ReportErrors() at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindProperty(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, ArgumentObject argument, LocalVariableSymbol local, EXPR optionalIndexerArguments, Boolean fEventsPermitted) at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindAssignment(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, ArgumentObject[] arguments, Dictionary`2 dictionary) at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.DispatchPayload(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, ArgumentObject[] arguments, Dictionary`2 dictionary) at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindCore(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding) at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding) at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)**strong text**
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have exactly this.